# How to make nav links re-appear/reset to default on browser resize after using javascript toggle function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, nav

I'm trying to code a responsive navbar using html/css/vanilla JS with multiple "break points", meaning on 815px and below I want have a partial nav visible with a drop down menu... Then on 600px and below I want the entire nav (besides home link) to be in a dropdown.

I kind of have it working using 2 javascript functions and RWD media queries but after using the onclick functions, the classes don't "reset" to their default states. I understand this is because the DOM has already loaded the CSS and now the onclick functions are changing their css rules.

So how do I get the nav to go back to displaying everything properly on window resize after using the functions?? Right now if you size down to either break point and use the onclick function, it won't display the nav links anymore once you resize the browser to tablet/desktop views..

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8x32qr14/13/

Thanks!

```js
var navOne = document.getElementsByClassName('navOne');
function displayNavOne() {
        for (i = 0; i < navOne.length; i++) {
          if (navOne[i].style.display === 'none' || navOne[i].style.display === '') {
            navOne[i].style.display = 'block';
            navOne[i].style.float = 'none';
            navOne[i].style.clear = 'both';
          } else {
            navOne[i].style.display = 'none';
            navOne[i].style.float = 'left';
            navOne[i].style.clear = 'none';
          }
        }
      }

      var navTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('navTwo');

      function displayNavTwo() {
        for (a = 0; a < navTwo.length; a++) {
          if (navTwo[a].style.display === 'none' || navTwo[a].style.display === '') {
            navTwo[a].style.display = 'block';
            navTwo[a].style.float = 'none';
            navTwo[a].style.clear = 'both';
          } else {
            navTwo[a].style.display = 'none';
            navTwo[a].style.float = 'left';
            navTwo[a].style.clear = 'none';
          }
        }
      }
```

```css
/* font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif; */

body {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 0.3em solid white;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: palevioletred;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: palevioletred;
}

.nav-container {
  margin: auto;
}

#bars,
#bars2 {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  display: none;
}

#bars:hover,
#bars2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-container {
    width: 75vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  .nav-container li:nth-child(5),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(6),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(7) {
    display: none;
  }
  #bars {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-container li:nth-child(2),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(3),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(4),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(5),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(6),
  .nav-container li:nth-child(7) {
    display: none;
  }
  #bars {
    display: none;
  }
  #bars2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4bfc31d982.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/master.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul id="main-nav">
          <div class="nav-container">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navTwo"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="navTwo"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li class="navTwo"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li class="navOne navTwo"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li class="navOne navTwo"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li class="navOne navTwo"><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li onclick="displayNavOne()" id="bars"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></li>
            <li onclick="displayNavTwo()" id="bars2"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An easier and lesser error prone method is to toggle a class to which the associated styles are set

Comment: @Nimsrules Thanks! that did the trick... for the most part. As long as you open **and close** the mobile nav before resize it's no problem. But if you leave it open and resize it will keep on the classes that make it mobile. How do I make it so whether the nav is open or close it will scale properly on window resize? thanks

Comment: new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k6taq3rf/

Comment: You can either change the styles of your class on different breakpoints using media queries or remove the class altogether detecting window resize - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: @nimsrules ah thanks! Don’t know why I didn’t think of putting the new class into RWD queries before x)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the window.matchMedia function. 
E’g window.matchMedia(“(min-width:600px)”). 
If the window width matches the media query width, then add the active classes accordingly. 
There is an example of this on my GitHub using one link that is visible within the nav menu on screens <600px (so you have to click the hamburger to see it) , and visible on the main nav (next to the logo) on screens bigger than 600px.

https://github.com/Hy-M/plants-project

Hope that helps.